# How to read title and description of a news websites

Tags: url, fetch

Some website like DIGG or NGOOR allow user to input an article or website URL then it will fetch that website title and description, display and images on its page. I searched around internet and also stackoverflow but cannot find any solutions that is the same as these websites. i planned to create this function using Java and Jquery, so i wonder if someone could help to give me some hints on this?

Moreover, in discussions related to this issue, some idea discussed on if we need to load all web page to read meta data tags or just load only necessary information? what's your ideas?

I am sorry if this post is an old question but i could not find any suitable data

Thank you very much.